# Cannot delete project

Tags: nest-device-access

I am unable to delete a project from the Nest Device Access Console. When I click the delete icon and click delete, it processes and comes back with a pop-up that says "Could not delete project" with no other information. If I try to delete the OAuth Client ID, it processes and comes back with a pop-up that says "Could not update project data" with no other info.

Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: this seemed to be just a temporary issue with the website.